# How to select all longer, shorter versions of the string, as well as the string itself

Tags: mysql

What would be the most elegant way to get all entries to a given record that are "longer", "shorter" or the same.

Here is an example:

Table 1

```
"1234567"   
"123456"    
"12345"   
"12346"  
"12355"    
"123"   
"12"
```

Suppose the original is "12345". Then I would like to select "1234567", "123456" (the longer versions), "123", "12" (The shorter versions) as well as the original "12345" from Table 1, but NOT "12346" and "12355".

I know how to do it using two queries, but is this possible to select the records with a single query?

Comment: Possible? Certainly. A good idea? Possibly not. Geneticists do this thing all the time, but my understanding is that they use sophisticated algorithms to crunch through the data in application code. - I'm open to correction however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two LIKE conditions:

```
select *
from t
where t.str like '12345%'
   or '12345' like concat(t.str, '%')
```

Demo: https://rextester.com/FGKMC15900

Read it as: Select all rows where the column value starts with the "original" string **or** the "original" string starts with the column value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT col1, 
    CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '12345%' AND LENGTH(col1) > LENGTH('12345') THEN 'longer' 
         WHEN col1 LIKE '12345%' AND LENGTH(col1) = LENGTH('12345') THEN 'same' 
         WHEN '12345' LIKE CONCAT(col1, '%') AND LENGTH(col1) < LENGTH('12345') THEN 'shorter' 
         ELSE '' END AS compared_length
FROM test
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzaz6GpfgZ3iBcnjiApybL/0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version, that uses a `WHERE` clause with a `REGEXP` to filter out unrelevant records ; then, all that is left to do is compare the lenghts of the strings :

```
SELECT
    col1,
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(col1) > LENGTH(@match) THEN 'longer'
        WHEN LENGTH(col1) < LENGTH(@match) THEN 'shorter'
        ELSE 'same'
    END result
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 REGEXP @match OR @match REGEXP col1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jzaz6GpfgZ3iBcnjiApybL/2) :**

```
SET @match = '12345';

SELECT
    col1,
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(col1) > LENGTH(@match) THEN 'longer'
        WHEN LENGTH(col1) < LENGTH(@match) THEN 'shorter'
        ELSE 'same'
    END result
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 REGEXP @match OR @match REGEXP col1;
```

```
| col1    | result  |
| ------- | ------- |
| 1234567 | longer  |
| 123456  | longer  |
| 12345   | same    |
| 123     | shorter |
| 12      | shorter |
```